# Call a function then a select a table in a view

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is this possible? I have a function which creates a table.

I want a view which can call the function then select on the table it creates. It needs to be a view as there is some php graph stuff on top which uses views to display its data.

Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vwi_spm_avg_enroll_rate AS
SELECT * FROM fn_spm_avg_enroll_rate();
SELECT * FROM avg_enroll_rate;
```

That doesn't work but I wondered if there was a way or if anyone knew a different way to do this?

Cheers
EDIT: CODE:

```
set search_path to "[study]", public;


DROP FUNCTION fn_spm_avg_enroll_rate();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_spm_avg_enroll_rate()
RETURNS VOID
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $proc$
DECLARE
    month1 text;
    month2 text;
    month3 text;
    month4 text;
    month5 text;
    month6 text;
    month7 text;
    month8 text;
    month9 text;
    month10 text;
    month11 text;
    month12 text;

    sqlStr text;
    sqlStr2 text;
    insertStr text;
    r record;

BEGIN 
    select to_char((current_date - interval '1 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month1;
    select to_char((current_date - interval '2 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month2;
    select to_char((current_date - interval '3 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month3;
    select to_char((current_date - interval '4 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month4;
    select to_char((current_date - interval '5 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month5;
    select to_char((current_date - interval '6 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month6;
    select to_char((current_date - interval '7 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month7;
    select to_char((current_date - interval '8 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month8;
    select to_char((current_date - interval '9 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month9;
    select to_char((current_date - interval '10 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month10;
    select to_char((current_date - interval '11 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month11;
    select to_char((current_date - interval '12 Month')::date,'Mon-YYYY') INTO month12;

    sqlStr := $$SELECT country_name,
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '12 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month12",
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '11 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month11",
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '10 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month10",
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '9 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month9",
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '8 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month8",
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '7 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month7",
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '6 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month6",
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '5 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month5",
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '4 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month4",
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '3 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month3",
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '2 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month2",
                SUM( CASE WHEN date_trunc('month', "C1".eldate::date) =  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 months' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS "month1"

            FROM country AS c
                INNER JOIN "site" AS s using (country_id)
                INNER JOIN "subject_C1" AS "C1" ON "s"."site_id" = "C1"."site_id"

            GROUP BY 1$$;

EXECUTE $$DROP TABLE avg_enroll_rate CASCADE$$;

EXECUTE $$CREATE TABLE avg_enroll_rate ("__SeriesName" VARCHAR(512), "__VectorX" VARCHAR(512), "__VectorY" INTEGER)$$; 


FOR r IN
        EXECUTE sqlStr
LOOP
        --RAISE NOTICE 'Record: %', r;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month12) || ',' || r.month12 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month11) || ',' || r.month11 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month10) || ',' || r.month10 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month9) || ',' || r.month9 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month8) || ',' || r.month8 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month7) || ',' || r.month7 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month6) || ',' || r.month6 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month5) || ',' || r.month5 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month4) || ',' || r.month4 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month3) || ',' || r.month3 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month2) || ',' || r.month2 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;
        sqlStr2 := 'INSERT INTO "avg_enroll_rate" VALUES ( ' || quote_literal(r.country_name) || ','  || quote_literal(month1) || ',' || r.month1 || ')';
        EXECUTE sqlStr2;


END LOOP;

END
$proc$
LANGUAGE 'PLPGSQL';
```

I'm new to sql so sorry if its rubbish code :(

Comment: is avg_enroll_rate the table that gets returned by your function? Can you edit your question and post your function code?

Comment: May my mind is too simple but why would you create a view to call a function with predefined arguments when you can simply call `SELECT` from a function call?

Comment: The function is a lot more complicated than a select. It creates a table with dynamic column names. So the table created always has different column names. 

@bluefeet yes it is, I can't post the code there's sensitive info in there, sorry

Comment: @AydinHassan can you edit the function (clean it) so you can post the code without including the sensitive info? I have the same issues with sensitive info that I have to remove before I can post anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code for the function, you are returning the table `avg_enroll_rate` instead of doing a `SELECT` on that table, you can just call your function and it should do the same thing.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vwi_spm_avg_enroll_rate AS
SELECT * 
FROM fn_spm_avg_enroll_rate();
-- SELECT * FROM avg_enroll_rate; this is unneeded because for function is returning the table
```

Then when you `SELECT` from your view you will get the data that you need from the `avg_enroll_rate` table since you returned it by calling the function.

Comment: Yes this is right, but not at the minute, the code above returns void. I was a bit confused as I have changed the layout of the table today. Before it was creating dynamic column names so: Country | Jan 2011 | Feb 2011 etc.

But now the dates are in the rows so the table is always going to be created with the same column names. So I just added a loop at the bottom to return the table and called the function from the view :) Thanks